# Calculation using JS not showing

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to build a web app in php something like stock maintenance, in my earlier page the user is allowed to insert the values of the bill which he gets from the dealer, as in from whom he buys the items which he sells from  his shop, hence there he inserts details about the products bought, quantity, price per pc and the rest, i mean total price and the grand total is calculated using JS.
now there is another page where the user sets his profit percent on the grand total(Grand total= total price of the products + Transportation price) and i want the selling price of each item to calculated on its own, using a button.
the rest details are being fetched from the database.
the user sets the profit% on the grand total and now i have used the JS to calculate for each item.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function poffy()
  {


      var d=document.getElementById("ui").value;
      var e=document.getElementById("grt").value;
      var p=parseFloat(d-e);
      var t=document.getElementById("noit").value;
      var e=p/parseFloat(t);
      for(var b=0;b<parseFloat(t);b++)
      {
      var c=document.getElementById("costprice").value;
      var y=new Array();
      y[b]=c;
      var f=document.getElementById("quant").value;
      var mk=new Array();
      mk[b]=f;
      var g=e/parseFloat(mk[b]);
      var h=g + parseFloat(y[b]);

      document.getElementById("sellprice").value=h;
      }
  }
  </script>
```

Now The problem is that the calculated value is being displayed only once and only for the first item ,not for the other rows.
[image: Error image]

My php code:

```
<?php
          include("connect.php"); 
    $wer='ccat';
    $i=0;
    $dater=date("D/M/Y");

    $sq="SELECT D_id FROM dealerdetail where Dealer='$wer'";
    $res=mysql_query($sq);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        $did=$row["D_id"];
    }

    $io="Select pdate,tranprice,grandtotal from dateprice where D_id='$did'";
    $qw=mysql_query($io);
      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qw)) 
     { 
         $pd=$row["pdate"];
         $as=$row["tranprice"];
         $as=0 + $as;
         $tr=$row["grandtotal"];
         $tr=0 + $tr;

    $sql="Select * from additem where Ditem_id='$did'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

              while($pop=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
              { 


      $b= $pop["Product"]; 
      $c= $pop["Brand"];
    $d= $pop["Model"];
    $e= $pop["Dprice"];
    $f= $pop["Quantity"];
    $t=$e*$f;
    $g= $pop["Quality"];


  echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td> $wer</td>";
    echo "<td> $b </td>";
    echo "<td> $c </td>";
    echo "<td> $d </td>";
    echo "<td><input type=text name=costprice id=costprice onkeyup=sell(); class=price value=$e /></td>";
    echo "<td><input type=text name=quantity[] class=quantity  id=quant value=$f /></td> ";
    echo "<td><input name=txt type=text class=txt value=$t readonly /></td> ";
    echo "<td><input type=text name=sellprice id=sellprice /></td>" ;
    echo "<td> <div align=center ><p>$g<p></div> </td>";
    /*echo "<td><input type=text name=purchasedt value=$pd /></td> "; */
    echo "<td><input type=text name=current value=$dater /></td>
  </tr>";
              $i++;

                /* if(isset($_POST['S.P']))
                  {
                      $po=$_POST['grandy'];
                      $ap=$po-$tr;
                      $ao=$ap/$i;
                      $ai=$ao/$f;
                      $ul=$_POST['costprice'];
                      $re=$ai + $ul;
                      echo $re;

                  }
               */




              }

              }

      echo "<label>Number Of Items :  </label> <input type=text name=no size=6 id=noit value=&nbsp;&nbsp;$i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
     echo " <label>Dealer Name :</label>&nbsp; &nbsp;<input type=text name=fetch id=fetc readonly />"; 
     echo "&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  <label>Purchase Date :</label>&nbsp; &nbsp;<input name=prdt type=text size=10 class=pur value=$pd readonly /> <br><br> ";



  ?> 
</table>
<?php
echo  "<br><br><label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Transport Price :</label><input type = text name=transport value=$as > <br>";
echo  "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Grand Total : </label> <input type = text name=grandy id=grt value=$tr > "; 
?>
<br >
<br >
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" name="proft" onclick="calcu();" value="Profit" />
<input type ="text" name="grandy" id="ui" />
```

Comment: IDs have to be unique, you can't use the same IDs on each row of the table. How is `getElementById()` supposed to know which one you want?

Comment: Sir I have kept the ids Unique

Comment: No you haven't. Your `while` loop puts `id=costprice` in every row of the table.

Comment: And the same with all the other IDs on the input fields.

Comment: The getElementById is fetching the value but only for the first row item. @Barnar

Comment: I know, that's what I've been saying. Since IDs are required to be unique, it only returns one element, and it's always the first one in the document. How is it supposed to know that you want the value from a different row? How should it guess which row you want?

Comment: Append a row number to all the IDs, and change `poffy()` so it takes the row number as an argument and appends it to the IDs before calling `getElementById`.

Comment: How to set unique ID sir,if i have not set..?

Comment: I just explained it in the last comment: Change the IDs to `costprice$row`, `quantprice$row`, and so on. Increment `$row` each time through the loop.

Comment: I understood what is the bug here,Please provide me the code to append unique ids to the row fields,so that poffy() can retrieve each value uniquely.

Answer (score 0):

I see you already have a variable `$i` that you're incrementing on every row, you can use that to make the IDs unique:

```
echo "<td><input type=text name=costprice id=costprice$i onkeyup=sell(); class=price value=$e /></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=quantity[] class=quantity  id=quant$i value=$f /></td> ";
echo "<td><input name=txt type=text class=txt value=$t readonly /></td> ";
echo "<td><input type=text name=sellprice id=sellprice$i /></td>" ;
```

Then change your Javascript to take a parameter that specifies the row:

```
function poffy(i)
{
    var d=document.getElementById("ui").value;
    var e=document.getElementById("grt").value;
    var p=parseFloat(d-e);
    var t=document.getElementById("noit").value;
    var e=p/parseFloat(t);
    for(var b=0;b<parseFloat(t);b++)
    {
        var c=document.getElementById("costprice"+i).value;
        var y=new Array();
        y[b]=c;
        var f=document.getElementById("quant"+i).value;
        var mk=new Array();
        mk[b]=f;
        var g=e/parseFloat(mk[b]);
        var h=g + parseFloat(y[b]);

        document.getElementById("sellprice"+i).value=h;
    }
}
```

I don't see where in your HTML you call the `poffy()` function. You need to change that code to pass the row number as a parameter.

I noticed another problem in your code. You have the following at the bottom of the table:

```
echo "<label>Number Of Items :  </label> <input type=text name=no size=6 id=noit value=&nbsp;&nbsp;$i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
echo " <label>Dealer Name :</label>&nbsp; &nbsp;<input type=text name=fetch id=fetc readonly />"; 
echo "&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  <label>Purchase Date :</label>&nbsp; &nbsp;<input name=prdt type=text size=10 class=pur value=$pd readonly /> <br><br> ";
```

Everything in a `<table>` has to be inside `<tr>` and `<td>` or `<th>` elements. You either need to put those wrappers around this line, or move them out of the table.